# Arduino:How to store large amonuts of data that come via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm having a problem about storage of large amounts of data.
I am trying to store large data sent from an iPhone into an aurdino, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: To help you solve your problem we need some detailed information.How large is the data? How often will you receive it? How long do you need to keep it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several places where to store data: EEPROM, RAM, external flash memory.

- [EEPROM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM) is good if you want access the data after reboot. But has limit of read-write cycles;
- RAM is fast, but you may need it for other application tasks, and it is volatile;
- flash is the best choice, but i guess you need to use external chip. Because internal flash has only about 10k write/read cycles.

More info about memory types [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=40586.0).

Comment: Think you, I will store data with using flash.But I didn't find the method to user it. I user the Arduino Due to store data, can you  give me some suggestes,?

Comment: What you need is called "In Application Programming" . Starting point is datasheet 20.4.4 page 321 http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11057-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3X-SAM3A_Datasheet.pdf